# Why won't Windows 8.1 find my files?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-search, file-search

I tried to search for `*.xls` in my documents, but it couldn't find them. I ran the 'Search Troubleshooter' but it couldn't find anything wrong. 'Users' is an indexed location. I just did a Windows Update.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
PrintSearch and Indexing Publisher details 

Potential issues that were checked 

Potential issues that were checked Detection details 

 Incorrect permissions on Windows Search directories Issue not present  

When permissions on the Windows Search data directories are set incorrectly, the search service might not be able to access or update the computer's search index. This can result in slow searches or incomplete search results. 

 Search Filter Host process failed Issue not present  

Problems with the Search Filter Host might indicate errors in the Windows Search service, which can cause searches to fail or return incomplete search results. 

 Windows Search service shut down unexpectedly Issue not present  

When the Windows Search service is forcibly shut down while performing maintenance, searches might fail or return incomplete search results. 

 Windows Search service shut down unexpectedly Issue not present  

When the Windows Search service is forcibly shut down, searches might fail or return incomplete search results. 

 Windows Search service not running Issue not present  

When the Windows Search service is not running, searches might be slower, and you might not be able to find all items. 

 Windows Search service failed Issue not present  

Problems with the Windows Search service can cause searches to fail or return incomplete search results. 

 Search Protocol Host process failed Issue not present  

Problems with the Search Protocol Host might indicate errors in the Windows Search service, which can cause searches to fail or return incomplete search results. 


Detection details Expand 

InformationalDirectory 
Windows Search data directory 
Directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\ 

InformationalUser-reported problems 
Problem Type: FilesMissingProblem 

Collection information 
Computer Name:  XPS 
Windows Version: 6.3 
Architecture: x64 
Time: Monday, April 17, 2017 11:41:45 AM 

Publisher details Expand 

Search and Indexing 
Find and fix problems with Windows Search. 
Package Version: 1.0 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows 
Search and Indexing 
Find and fix problems with Windows Search. 
Package Version: 1.0 
Publisher: Microsoft Corporation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that **Indexing Options** dialog, click **Advanced**, and then **Rebuild** next to "Delete and rebuild index".

This will force Windows to re-scan your computer for files and re-create the index that is used for searches.